# question about manifolds

Tags: manifolds

when we say that :"topological space M admits (for example)30 differential structure."
is it means that for some fixed topology, M admits 30 differential structure or for different topology?

Comment: When you say "topological space $M$..." this means that you have fixed a topological structure $T$ on a certain set $X$: $M=(X,T)$. Notice that you did not say "a set $M$ admits ..." (the latter would allow for different topologies on $M$).

Answer (score 0):

This simply means that the $30$ structures are homeomorphic, but *not* diffeomorphic $-$ i.e., they have the same topology, but they have different smooth functions.